# Как работает Aria-hidden

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

На многих сайтах по бутстарпу вижу следующий код для вставки иконки:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Зачем нужно вот это указание aria-hidden?

Это хорошая практика или вредная, неправильная?

Обычно я не люблю вставлять код, который не понимаю, поэтому вычищаю `aria-hidden`. Но возможно, я неправ и пришла пора разобраться с этим вопросом.

Я поискал информацию в сети, но найденное меня ещё больше сбило с толку.

Похоже, что этот тег как-то помогает слабовидящим пользователям ориентироваться на странице, но как именно - я не понимаю.

Прошу помочь прояснить вопрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474099/what-is-html5-aria

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden здесь все подробно расписано про `aria`

Comment: Вы знаете, я вполне сносно читаю по-английски, но тема для меня и на русском достаточно непонятная и ещё и новые термины вводит. Я сейчас начитаюсь и только больше себя запутаю. Если несложно - можно сначала по-русски ответ дать, а потом уже привести ссылки на английском для дополнительного чтения?

Comment: в общем эти атрибуты как бы для семантики т.е желаемое отображение и относится это больше к мобильной части ... вроде так но на самом деле не ясно и мне как это работает

Comment: aria - это атрибуты связанные с доступностью. Данный атрибут прячет данный блок от экранах читалок.

Answer (score 8):

Вообще аттрибуты `aria` нужны для людей с ограниченными возможностями а также для режима чтения. В вашем случае `aria-hidden` означает что элемент показывать необязательно. Практика бесспорно хорошая.

Answer (score 1):

aria-hidden делает так, чтобы экраночиталка для незрячих не читала этот элемент. например, когда с клавиатуры незрячий доходит до изображения, говорилка говорит: (графика). если стоит aria-hidden, то говорилка сфокусирует на следующем элементе, пропуская изображение. зачем оно незрячему.
К некоторым изображениям лучше прописать alt-text или aria-label, чтобы изображение читалось говорилкой.
приведу пример, но не знаю, как сделать изображение.

```
<img src="..." aria-label="собака сидит на полу и смотрит на миску с едой"></img>
```

это просто пример, не факт, что он будет работать. я незрячий, и на сайтах никогда не совал изображения.